# Xcode 9 Push notification capability missing

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Push notification settings are missing from

> Target->Capabilities->

I can not enable push notifications. Previously app was not supporting push notifications. Project was compiled in old Xcode version. In Xcode 9.0 Push notification capability was missing. 
[image]

Comment: You should see it after iCloud (2nd item in the capability section). I am using the latest Xcode and i can see it in my xcode.

Comment: I have latest Xcode as well. These options are available in other projects but not in this one. I changed apple id and bundle identifier and options were gone.

Comment: Force close and reopen xcode. Hope this will solve your issue. I don't see any reason of not showing the push notification in your end.

Comment: Nope. Does not work.

Comment: Check out my answer @SaqibOmer

Comment: Yup, Issue was resolved already. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Xcode 9 you have to select an account enrolled in the Apple Developer Program, using an account in Xcode by signing in using your apple ID isn't enough, the account has to be enrolled in the developer program. When you select such account the list of capabilities you can set changes and you can now see the Push notifications capability. 
Check out this [Advanced App Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/) from Apple